# Rails Devise Requires Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have seen many threads on them, however none solved the issue for me (other people's issues were solved). I am trying to sign in via username password and no email, but I get
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1

Here is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #devise :omniauthable
 include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
 devise :authentication_keys => [:username]
end
```

In devise.rb:

```
config.confirmation_keys = [ :username ]
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
```

I have really no idea where the error could be..

Comment: Try defining this method in `User` model `def email_required?
  false
end`

Comment: Have you override devise views properly ? You can find every answer to your question here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: I went through the link and did every step, yet it did not work. I don't know why it seemed to have solved the issue for other people.

Comment: @Sontya tried it, did not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the changes?

Comment: Yes I did, I did it the painful of overwriting DeviseTokenAuth.